# Identify xml text elements with Schematron

Tags: xml, schematron

Is it possible to make a rule in XPath which identifies xml elements like this one:

```
<A>something...<A>
```

?

I am using Schematron and I need to specify that some elements must not have children like the one in the example, that's why I need to identify them.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

For the following input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <a>Only Text</a>
  <a><b>Child node</b></a>  
  <a><b>Child node</b>Mixed content</a>
</root>
```

These Schematron rules should do what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<iso:schema xmlns:iso="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron">
<iso:pattern id="children tests">
    <iso:rule context="a">
        <iso:assert test="child::node()">
            Element has nodes
        </iso:assert>
        <iso:report test="child::*">
            Element has child elements
        </iso:report>
        <iso:assert test="empty(child::text())">
            Element has text
        </iso:assert>
        <iso:report test="child::text() and empty(child::*)">
            Element has only text
        </iso:report>               
    </iso:rule>
</iso:pattern>
</iso:schema>
```

[image: Testing Schematron rules in XML ValidatorBuddy]